# Local storage to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, storage, local

I hope someone will help me. I was using local storage as my database in my system and wants to change it into mongodb. The thing is, I am defining ng local storage in javascript, and wanted to change and but I don't know how. Can you please help me? Thank you!

I used nodejs on this and already installed mongodb and other dependencies.

Below is the sample code of my javascript with local storage

```
`var usersRecord = getCrudData() ? getCrudData() : [];
var register = require('./register-success');
//Check if email conforms to proper format
function checkEmailIfValid() {
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
        alert('Please provide a valid email address. Example: testuser@mail.com');
        email.focus;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
function getCrudData(){
    let arr=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
    return arr;
}

function setCrudData(arr){
    localStorage.setItem('users',JSON.stringify(arr));
}
```

`

Comment: Instead of local storage, make calls to the node server via fetch API. And then the server side needs to handle the calls in its endpoints, where it saves or reads the data into/from mongo.

Comment: Thank you for responding. May I request some examples for this? Also, do I need to remove the local storage in the javascript code I gave?

Comment: Yes, you would replace the local storage part with the code, that calls the server.

Comment: yay thanks, can you show me some examples for this? TIA!

Comment: The code is not formatted correctly, likely due to the back-apostrophe at the beginning.  Use a sequence of three back-apostrophes at the beginning and end of your code block to correctly format your code.